# Elliptic integral of the first kind

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to plot the integral $$I(\phi) = \int_0^{\phi} \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\sqrt{1 +\sin(\theta)^2}}$$

In *Mathematica* notation, it is a case of an elliptic integral of the first kind with $m=-1$,

$F(\phi| m) = \int_0^{\theta} \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\sqrt{1-m \sin(\theta)^2}}$, so I have $I(\phi) = F(\phi| -1)$.

In Maple notation, it is a case of an elliptic integral of the first kind with $k = i$,

$F(\sin(\phi), k) = \int_0^{\theta} \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin(\theta)^2}}$, so I have $I(\phi) = F(\sin(\phi), i)$.

Upon plotting $I(\phi)$ and $F(\phi| -1)$ in *Mathematica* I find perfect agreement.

Upon plotting $I(\phi)$ (in red) and $F(\sin(\phi), i)$ (in green) in Maple I get the result below:

[image: Maple output]

How can such a difference arise?

EDIT:

Code for *Mathematica*:

```
F1 = Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + Sin[p]^2], {p, 0, phi}]
F2 = EllipticF[phi, -1]
```

Code for Maple:

```
F1:= int(1/sqrt(1+sin(theta)^2), theta=0..phi)
F2:= EllipticF(sin(phi), I)
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: (1) It seems the question may be properly be about the behavior of Maple, which is off-topic on this site. (2) The green graph looks like `Re@EllipticF[ArcSin[Sin@\[Theta]], I]` -- as Louis implies, no one can be sure about the problem with your code, if you don't share it.

Comment: I edited to give my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't have/know Maple, but from [the Maple doc. here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=EllipticF), it seems that Maple's `EllipticF[z, k]` is equivalent to `EllipticF[ArcSin[z], k^2]`  in *Mathematica*, in which case the problem is due to the periodicity of sine and the branch cuts of arc sine.

Comment: The main problem, as Michael notes, is that Maple and *Mathematica* are using different argument conventions. In particular, Maple's `EllipticF()` is in fact directly equivalent to *Mathematica*'s `InverseJacobiSN[]`. `EllipticF[]` uses a different argument convention, and is built so as not to have unneeded branch cuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mathematica notation

```
$Assumptions = ϕ ∈ Reals

F[ϕ_, m_] := 
Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - m Sin[θ]^2], {θ, 0, ϕ}]

Plot[F[ϕ, -1], {ϕ, - Pi,  π}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

In Maple notation

```
F[\[Phi]_, k_] := 
Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - k^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2], {\[Theta], 0, \[Phi]}]

Plot[F[\[Phi], I], {\[Phi], -2 Pi, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

In maple

[image]

Comment: And when you plot $F(\sin(\phi),i)$ in Maple what do you get? I get the strange plot in the question.

Comment: @Nigel1 same result, I edit my answer

Comment: Thanks - but when you compare it to "built in" Maple EllipticK function with code: EllipticF(sin(phi), I) do you reproduce my plot in question or the Mathematica result?